# Use of uninitialized value but variables declared

Tags: perl, if-statement

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $last_variable2= 'abc'; 
print "last var2 $last_variable2\n";

my @grouped;

while (<DATA>) {


    my ($variable1, 
        $variable2, 
        $other_data) = split ',',$_,3;

    if($variable2 ne 'abc'){
            if( $variable2 ne $last_variable2){
                   print "\n\n"; 

                   print "'$variable2' doesn't equal '$last_variable2'\n";

                   my %HoA;
                   &process_data(@grouped_series);

                   @grouped = ();

             }
   }else{

       print "Skipped this because it's the first\n";

   }

   push @grouped_series, $_;

   $last_variable2 = $variable2;




}
```

When I run this code, I keep getting

```
Use of uninitialized value $last_variable2 in string ne at 1_1_correspondencer.pl line 32, <DATA> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $variable2 in string ne at 1_1_correspondencer.pl line 33, <DATA> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $last_variable2 in concatenation (.) or string at 1_1_correspondencer.pl line 36, <DATA> line 6.
```

But, I initialized both variables. Sorry, this is a naive question--I only just started using `strict` and `warnings`

Comment: Try to print `$_` inside `while`. Maybe `$_` does not contain any `,` that results in `$variable2` equals undef and the errors above are displayed.

Comment: the problem is from warnings, not strict. the `my` makes it defined but not initialized. that would come from `split`, which probably doesn't have enough commas in $_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing your DATA, you don't verify that each of these variables is defined:

```
my ($variable1, 
    $variable2, 
    $other_data) = split ',',$_,3;
```

If there are no commas on a row, then `$variable2` would be undefined which is later assigned to `$last_variable2`.  Maybe add some data verification to take into account that case?

```
if (! defined $variable2) {
    warn "missing variable2 definition: $_\n";
}
```

Without seeing your actual data, we can't really advise you more.